# Excluding a group in Tableau Filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have 20Fruits and I have grouped them into 4 groups namely :Summer fruits, Winter fruits, Autumn fruits and Spring fruits. Now when I place a Fruit filter, I do not want the Autumn group to be visible in the drop down at all in Tableau. Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried creating a set that doesn't include Autumn fruit and placing that set in filter and then refreshing the fruit filter, but it doesn't work. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Fruit_Group (Fruit Loop?) field on the filter shelf and select the seasons you wish to include. Then right click on the Fruit_Group field on the filter shelf and **Add to Context**

Tableau will apply the context filters early in the process, before populating your other filter controls.

Finally, show a filter for your original Fruit field. The filter control should only show fields for the selected seasons.

The above solution works well when you are deciding as the visualization designer which seasons to include. There is at least one other, similar solution, that applies well if you are allowing people to choose their seasons.

In that case, don't add Fruit_Group to the context. Instead, show both the Fruit_Group and Fruit filters, but set the Fruit_Group filter control to show all values in database, and set the Fruit filter control to only show relevant values. You can change those settings by clicking on the tiny caret at the top right of the filter controls. Those settings should happen naturally if you first put Fruit and Fruit_Group into a hierarchy (which is an optional step)

Answer (score 1):

This is easy since you have already constructed your group:

Just make a copy of your group (**Right Click** | **Duplicate**). Drag your copy group to the filters and filter out the option you want but **Do not Show** this filter. Then drag your original group to the filters and now **Show* this filter. You will not see the pre-filtered out option in this filter anymore.

Comment: You are welcome :) You may consider accepting the answer if it is worked for you.